# How to stop button from animating when setting the title of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift3

When we want to set the text of a UIButton, we need to execute the below code:

```
myButton.setTitle("My Text", forState: .normal)
```

The only problem is, when the text changes, an animation happens like this:

[image]

Is there a way to set the title of a button without it animating?

I would like the button to act as a standard UILabel, however I would also like it to call a function when it is pressed on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set values inside UIView's `performWithoutAnimation` and it will do just as it states. But you will also need to call `layoutIfNeeded` so they relayout happens during the block.

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
  self.myButton.setTitle(newTitle, forState: .Normal)
  self.myButton.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: That works. Plus it also shows the animation if I were to click that button, which I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use myButton.setTitle("My Text", forState: .normal) for all Uibuttoncontrolstate.

Comment: That is the code I am already using

Comment: Have you tried same title for all UIControlState ? Normal, highlighted , selected. When we click on button it shows selected state title. When we set same title, it will not animate.